# How does one call a function that returns a flag and internally re-sets this flag to false?

Tags: c

Imagine the following code:

```
static char myFlag;

void setFlagTo_1(void)
{
  myFlag = 1;
}

char hasFlagChangedTo_1(void)
{
  char retval = myFlag;

  myFlag = 0;

  return retval;
}
```

How would one describe the function named `hasFlagChangedTo_1`. How would you call/describe this action?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... do you want to *automatically* have the function called when the value of `myFlag` changes?

Comment: `read_clear` or `read_reset`?

Comment: There are many ways to answer this question -- an attribute that makes the question inappropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: This question more belongs to programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: The function can be *described* more clearly by understanding the context in which it is used/called. Depends on the application you are developing.

Comment: @Mike no, one of these usages could be: having a millisecond timer interrupt set a 'second' flag. You can then use a get_flag and clear_flag for instance. But this functionality could also be combined. I was looking for a name of this type of combined functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call it `testAndClear` analog to that testAndSet-functions...

Answer (score 2):

I would write it like this:

```
void clearFlag(char *oldValue)
{
    if (oldValue)
        *oldValue = myFlag;
    myFlag = 0;
}
```

When you call the function you can pass `NULL`. But if you pass a pointer to a variable, you can name that variable such that the code at the call site makes it obvious what is going on.

```
clearFlag(&oldValue);
```

The problem with using a function that returns a value is that you typically name those functions with the name of the value that is returned. But if the function has a strong side effect, that won't be captured in the name.

When there are side effects, it is often a good idea to use a `void` function and a name that describes the side-effects.

Answer (score 2):

I would call such a function `retrieveFlag`.

When it's there, you retrieve it, so afterwards it isn't there anymore. When it isn't there, it returns false.

**Edit:** Or just call it `getAndResetFlag` - does exactly what it says on the tin.

Answer (score 0):

ResetFlag , As it is resetting the flag value